# 389DS multi master replication with TLS

Tags: ldap, 389-ds

I would like to replace our existing Directory Server with 389DS multi master replication. Also TLS need to enable for sssd client configuration.

I have searched on internet and did single 389DS but I am not able to configure TLS properly. Could anyone can share me the link which I can refer for the same.

Answer (score 0):

389DS TLS Setup is in this document: https://directory.fedoraproject.org/docs/389ds/howto/howto-ssl.html

On a machine with the sssd LDAP packages installed, the man page sssd-ldap(5) will have the documentation you need. Also, Red Hat's documentation on configuring sssd is pretty good: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system-level_authentication_guide/sssd